# belongs_to association in nested form does not post data correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms

I am having some difficulty to figure out why the post data from the form is not posted correctly.

I have to models: Child and Parent

in the form of Child i am nesting a form of Parent in this way:

```
<%
parent = (child.parent) ? parent : Parent.new
%>
<%=f.fields_for :parent, parent do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'parent_fields', :fp => builder %>
<% end %>
```

The parent_fields form is as follows:

```
<% @all_parents = Parent.all %>
<% parent = fp.object %>
<%= fp.fields_for :parent do |builder| %>
       <%= builder.input :parent_id, :as => :select, :label => 'Parent: ', :required => false, 
         :collection => options_from_collection_for_select(@all_parents, "id", "name", parent.id), :include_blank => '- Select -' %>
 <% end %>
```

The posted data hash shows as follows:

```
"parent_attributes"=>{"parent"=>{"parent_id"=>"6"}, "id"=>"36"}
```

where 36 is the old parent id and 6 is the new one.

When i do update_attributes it does not work which is normal because it would work if the hash would be like this way:

```
...    
"parent_id" => 6
"parent_attributes"=>{"id"=>"36", ....}
...
```

I am working on a legacy code. It is also possible that data was modified by javascript. The purpose of this post is to make sure that the way I am writing the form is the right way because I am new to nested forms.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibly scenarios you want to consider:
1. A child needs to *select an existing* parent it belongs to.
2. A child needs to *create a brand new* parent that it belongs to.

It appears that you want to do #1, *select* an existing parent. If so, you do not need `fields_for`. Fields for is for creating new relations.

I'll show you some example code from an application I'm working on about schools, where a student `belongs_to` a grade level.

**app/views/students/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @student do |student_form| %>
    <%= student_form.text_field :first %>
    <%= student_form.text_field :last %>
    <%= student_form.collection_select :grade_level_id, GradeLevel.all, :id, :name %>
    <%= student_form.submit "Save" %>
  <% end %>
```

Now, using your models (Child and Parent):

**app/views/children/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @child do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :child_name %>
  <%= form.number_field :age %>
  <%= form.collection_select :parent_id, Parent.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= form.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that I just put `Parent.all` straight into the `collection_select`. Creating `@all_parents` above isn't necessary.

**EDIT**

If you want to create new parents every time...

**app/views/children/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @child do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :child_name %>
  <%= form.number_field :age %>
  <% form.fields_for :parent, @child.parent do |parent_fields| %>
    <%= parent_fields.text_field :parent_name %>
  <%= form.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I understand this would work for parent_id. How do you manage to write other fields of parent. say parent has fields: field1, and field2 that you want to update using child.update_attributes. Just to make it clear, I need just the form because in console that works for me (This means the models are properly set).

Comment: Let me know how that works. The rest of the documentation for `fields_for` is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for